# Does CakePHP make tables in database when installing?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

It's my very first time installing and using CakePHP on localhost. I've accomplished all the steps that are required in order to install CakePHP. After installing I checked my database and it is not showing me any tables in my database. Is something wrong or does CakePHP not insert any tables while installing?

Below is my status of CakePHP:

> Your version of PHP is 5.2.8 or higher.
>
> Your tmp directory is writable.
>
> The FileEngine is being used for core caching. To change the config
>   edit APP/Config/core.php
>
> Your database configuration file is present.
>
> Cake is able to connect to the database.
>
> CakePHP: the rapid development php framework  (default) 0 query took
>   ms    Nr  Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong. CakePHP doesn't create any tables for you because it cannot know what tables your application will use.

Comment: Hmm , so does it means that by default cake php does not make any tables in database and only i have to make the table in database according to my needs?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. CakePHP is a framework and not a CMS that comes with a predefined set of tables. For example, if you write a blog application you will need different tables than if you write a shop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bake console to setup and create the database after the basic installation. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html

Answer (score 1):

A typical Cake workflow is

1. Create your tables following [Model an database conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)
2. Generate the application code [using bake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html)
3. Refine the application